# Astral Doubles (Avatar)

Tags: super-powers, alternate-reality, alternate-earth, abilities, class-structure

This might be entirely opinion based which is frowned upon in world building but I really do need help on this.

I’m writing a story of an alternative version of Earth where almost 80% of its population has the innate ability to manifest avatars which are an extension of their life force, the avatars come in different shapes and sizes and are usually humanoid or beast like in appearance. They are able to alter and warp reality giving their hosts powers and abilities.

Now I have 3 different classes for the different types of avatars but I want at least 4:

- the first class is avatars being outside the host (operating at the hosts side),
- the second being the avatar being inside the host almost like a symbiote(operating from within on out)
- the third class can be wielded by the host as a weapon.

I need help on what the fourth class should be, I want this class somehow related or connected to the body as all the other classes are but any ideas on how I might go about this are welcomed and would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Your description of the third class seems to contradict "usually humanoid". You could play it for laughs though, like a man swinging around a garden gnome as a bat

Comment: Hi user56901, what's up with the most recent edit? It looks like you've completely removed the question. We generally encourage questions to be left intact even if you've found an answer or had it closed, so that people visiting later can learn something too.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of ideas:

Your fourth class could be a type of avatar capable of possessing/hijacking other people. Normally incorporeal, or only visible as a faint blur, they can possess people for short periods of time - accessing memories, or dictating their actions.

Alternatively a bit of a combination of the weapon/outside avatar concept in that the user physically fuses with the avatar, becoming a hybrid creature with the best traits of both

Comment: I like the first idea - an avatar that can works like class 2 except not on you. Though you may need body contact to activate (or maintain) the effect and actual class 2 users are probably immune.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the 3rd class into two different classes:

- the class of kinetic weapons, where something is projected toward the target and deals damage by transferring kinetic energy. Think bow and arrow, gun, etc.
- the class of non projectile instruments, which can accomplish a function but cannot leave the host body. This can be a club (still a weapon) but also a binocular or a hammer, so not a weapon in strict sense.

Answer (score 0):

**A pet avatar**
Not a starry sword you wield,
a real(well ... :/) pet or monster you can summon to help you,

Other things:
- the pet has a mind and doesn't just do what you say.
sometimes its sassy, sometimes its waves you into sleep.
    ? Maybe it can even speak ?
- or not ... The pet is controlled by you and does exactly what you say

Hope this helps :)
please comment cool extension and thoughts about this

Comment: I was thinking about this one but this goes in to the first class where the avatar is kind of a pet of sorts and stands along side the host as a kind of ethereal body guard and listens to the hosts commands, the host is powerless while the avatar can access the power. And there are rare avatars who can communicate and who are sentient. Thanks so much though! I appreciate it! Feel free to comment any more ideas you have!

Answer (score 0):

### Avatar that exists in other dimensions

This avatar can exist in other dimensions or planes of existence and interact with beings on that planes.

### Avatar that can exist in different points in time

The persons projection exists in the past or in the future. The user can interact through these avatars with those times to some extent. The farther he sends the avatar forward or back in time the harder it is to interact with that time.